# Is there a difference between the method of helper and library are called upon in code igniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-helpers

I am getting little bit confused, the way the methods of library and helper are used in code igniter. I am still learning code igniter.

CONTROLLER

```
function index(){
    $this->load->helper('text');
    $this->load->library('auth'); //custom library

    $data['string'] = 'this is sample ..... this is sample';
    $this->load->view('article', $data);
}
```

VIEW

```
<?php 
if(is_logged_in()){    //is_logged_in() is the method from the library, 'auth'
    echo 'You are logged in';
}
<p><?php echo word_limiter($string, 10); ?></p> <!--word_limiter() is the method from the helper, 'text' -->
```

In the above view file, the helper method `word_limiter()` works fine. But the method `is_logged_in()` does not work. But if I do (`$this->auth->is_logged_in()`), it will work.

But why the method from helper i.e. `word_limiter()` does not have to be written like this (`$this->text->word_limiter()`).

Is there a difference between the method of helper and library are called upon ?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

A CodeIgniter helper is a set of related functions (Common functions) which you could use them  within *Models*, *Views*, *Controllers*,.. everywhere.

Once you load (include) that file, you can get access to the functions.

But a Library is a class, which you need to make an instance of the class (by `$this->load->library()`). And you'll need to use the object `$this->...` to call the methods.

**As a thumb rule:** A library is used in object oriented context (Controller, ...), while a helper is more suitable to be used within the *Views* (non object oriented).

Answer (score 3):

CI Helper may or may not have class

But Library must have class representation.

Refer this SO Answer

[CodeIgniter: Decision making for creating of library & helper in CodeIgniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361370/codeigniter-decision-making-for-creating-of-library-helper-in-codeigniter)

Comment: yea, that link provided me with a more clarification.